# HTML 5 geolocator does not work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I just built a test app which makes use of google map and HTML locator, everything works fine locally but the geolocator does not working in production.

Comment: It works in other browsers except chrome

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome requires that the page is served via `https` for HTML5 geolocator to work. From Chrome 50, users will not be allowed to get locations of users using non-secure origins.

See here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only for details.

To serve a Ruby on Rails application via HTTPS there are 3 steps you need to follow:

Obtain an SSL certificate
Configure the web server to use the SSL certificate
Configure the Ruby on Rails application for HTTPS

Read more at https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/using-https-with-ruby-on-rails#sOx3fC0WgvCJD5gP.99